# Is variable importance a two way route?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost, gbm

Assuming I have a dataset, `dt`, with 20 variables, `var1, var2, var3, ..., var20`

And i run a `xgboost` using:

```
import xgboost as xgb
Y = dt['var1']
X = dt.drop(columns='var1')
model = xgb.XGBRegressor()
model.fit(X,Y)
```

From this model I can get the variable importance using `model.feature_importances_`

My question is, if `var2` scores high on the variable importance when `Y = dt['var1']` and `X = dt.drop(columns='var1')`, does this **necessarily** mean that `var1` will also score high on the variable importance when  `Y = dt['var2']` and `X = dt.drop(columns='var2')` ? If not, why ?

Comment: have a look here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162162/relative-variable-importance-for-boosting

Comment: and another question, you can try it or? just change the code and see what happenes ;)